# macro to parse latex token as a string

Tags: macros

I have a macro (here `\mymacro`) that receives a command as one of the inputs (specifically a command of type `\includegraphics{..}`).

The macro reads as

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[4]{%
something{#1}
...
}%
```

and is called as

```
\mymacro{\includegraphics{..}}{..}{..}{..}
```

I am now in the necessity of parse the the content of the first argument as a string to extract content (i.e. parse the token `\includegraphics{..}` itself to extract file name and modifiers). I will use `xstring` parsing commands for the purpose.

In other words, I'd like to turn `\mymacro` into something like

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[4]{%
something{#1}
\stringparsingcommands{ \as__a__string{#1}   }
...
}%
```

My question is:

how to build such `\as__a__string` command? It needs to prevent `#1` to be expanded as token and convert it into string.

I've been trying with `\verbtocs` from the package `\xstring`, yet with no success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you be interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution?

Comment: I've never used it, but it should be compatible with a `tikzexternalize` execution

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a bit more background information as to what's supposed to happen with the first argument of `\mymacro`. E.g., will it always be of the form `\includegraphics{<some string>}`, i.e., will it always start with `\includegraphics` and end with some material (a "string"?) that's encased in matching curly braces? If this is not the actual structure of the first argument, do please provide more in-depth information as to what should be expected.

Comment: I can write the specific case, I don't think it will help, though - the string parsing or the specifics of the `\includegraphics` call are irrelevant, I believe. 
I think the point is:    from a call `\mymacro{\command{string}}` can one extract and e.g. display in the manuscript the string `\command{string}` *as is* (i.e. not expanded)?

Comment: why do you need to do this though, `\includegraphics` (or rather keyval) is already going to parse the argument and is already going to and report the filename and various options, you can use the result of that parse.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, would you please be more explicit in the way to use them?

Comment: @Acorbe `\includegraphics` just parses that argument and leaves all the values available to be used by the various back ends, that's _all_ it does, it doesn't actually include any graphics as that is system specific  look at eg dvips.def which gets the scale as \Gin@scalex \Gin@scaley, the bounding box as  \Gin@llx \Gin@lly \Gin@urx \Gin@ury etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?  EDITED to further extract optional and primary argument from 1st argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\mymacro[4]{%
  \parsefurther#1\endparse%
}
\def\parsefurther#1#2\endparse{The argument of \detokenize{#1} is 
  ``\detokenize{#2}''.\\
  \detectoptional{#2}[#2]\enddetect%
}
\def\detectoptional#1[#2]#3\enddetect{%
  \ifx\relax#3\relax Optional: none.  Primary: \detokenize{#1}.
  \else \extractoptional#1%
  \fi
}
\newcommand\extractoptional[2][]{Optional: \detokenize{#1}. 
                                 Primary: \detokenize{#2}.}
\begin{document}
\mymacro{\includegraphics{this_is_the_argument}}{..}{..}{..}

\mymacro{\specialincludegraphics[options]{this_is_the_argument}}{..}{..}{..}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: let me try.... 1 minute

Comment: !! Nice!! Thanks.. adapted to the purpose :) ... needed to extract the right filenames to properly tikzexternalize images post-processed with tikz.

Comment: @Acorbe  Thanks.  I added a few bells and whistles.

Comment: :) it's a great technical insight..too bad I can upvote only once.. thanks :)